Problems wit running CAN in Micropython on a pyboard 1,1
Pyboard, micropython, CAN hardware
I have a pyboard v1.1 with micropython running and I want to use CAN to communicate between modules at 250K and 500K.
I am using CAN 1(Y3 = RX = B8, Y4 = TX) = B9). The CAN transciever is terminated with a 120 resistor between CANH, CANL
The code at micropython just does not work.  I get an OSError 16 after 3 transmissions!
**
Note that CAN Loopback works.**
>>> can.info()
[128, 0, 1, 1, 0, 3, 0, 0]

This is the version of Micropython on the pyboard.
YD-MPY v1.12 on 2020-07-16; vcc-gnd(R) pyboard(R) with STM32F405RG

Type "help()" for more information.

>>> 

I am looking for some assistance in getting the pyboard to work in transmiting and receiving successfuly over CAN.
I will require code and anything else to make it work.
Here is sample code that throws exceptions.
import pyb

can = CAN(1, CAN.NORMAL)
can.init(CAN.NORMAL, prescaler=16, sjw=1, bs1=8, bs2=3)  # Example settings

def send_message():
    try:
        can.send('Hello', 123)  # Message with ID 123
    except OSError as e:
        if e.args[0] == 16:  # EBUSY
            print("CAN bus is busy, retrying...")
            pyb.delay(10)  # Delay before retrying
            send_message()
        else:
            print("Unexpected error:", e)

for _ in range(5):
    send_message()
    pyb.delay(100)  # Delay between transmissions

The pyboard just does not work.  I have tried several boards and transcievers and it does not work.
I get OS Error 16 after 3 transmissions.

Which other node is on your CAN bus? Does this node receive your messages? Is the data sent at all? Can you confirm using a scope?
